# How do you make a computed field both computed and databound to a field?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I know how to bind a computed field to a document field.  And I know how to use javascript to compute a computed field.  But how do I do both?

Say my javascript in the computed field is:

```
 @Name("[ABBREVIATE]" ,@UserName());
```

How do I bind that to say document1.ReqName field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the computed field's Value, use Advanced data binding and select Expression Language (EL).
The expression to use is simply "document1.ReqName" (no quotes).

Comment: But how do I get the default value of @Name("[ABBREVIATE]" ,@UserName());?   What I currently do is to use two fields one an editbox that is CSS hidden, has a default value and is bound to a field.   Then I have a computed field that computes off of the edit box.

Answer (score 3):

I use two fields:

1. a hidden input field that computes the required value (using the xp:inputHidden control). I use "default value" to emulate Computed when composed - and converters to emulate Computed ([inspired by Tommy Valand](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.dk/2010/02/xpages-use-converters-to-emulate-domino.html)).
2. a visible computed field or a visible input field set to read only that does the same calculation. Perhaps this can be changed to display the value of the hidden input field using getComponent("").getValue()?

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much what I do now, see above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I miss the Point but why don't You simply do the following?

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.Reader}">
    <xp:this.defaultValue>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:@Name("[ABBREVIATE]",@UserName());}]]>
    </xp:this.defaultValue>
</xp:inputText>
```

This is a Textfield bound per EL to the DocumentField. If the field is empty it is calculated by the default value.

Great! - I missed the point. But You can try this one:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript: 
                    if(@IsNewDoc()){
                          document1.replaceItemValue("Reader",@Name("[ABBREVIATE]",@UserName()));
                    }
                    return document1.getItemValue("Reader");}]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bind in this case. I would bind every other control and in this case manually add that into the document field directly with script before the save action.

so something like: (forgive the code not at my work comp)

```
<eventhandler>
   <actionGroup>
      <script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
         doc.replaceItemValue("ReqName", @Name("[ABBREVIATE]" ,@UserName()));
      }]]><script>

      <saveDocument></saveDocument>
   </actionGroup>
</eventhandler>
```

Comment: Also thought about going this route.  There should be an easier way.  There should be a get and set method for binding.  I suppose a convertor could also be employed?

Comment: well thats up for debate, XPages is just an extension of JSF, so any issues here would need to be dealt with the underlying platform. Well what type of convertor? this is just script so you can add the name to a var and manipulate it how you like and then pass it in. if you wanted to use the inbuilt convertors, it would be more like Per's suggestion with a hidden input field, convertor applied and the script pulling that value with getComponent().getValue(). I'd most likely modify it with script and then pass it to .repaceItemValue

Answer (score 0):

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedFieldTest1">
[CDATA[#{javascript:
  var userName = "Username: "+("Reader",@Name("[ABBREVIATE]",@UserName()));
  currentDocument.replaceItemValue("computedFieldTest1",userName);
  return userName;
  }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```