# how to bind data from a computed field in xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to bind the data to a FORM from a computed field which calculates the amount according to the number of days selected.Please help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make a computed field both computed and databound to a field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104900/how-do-you-make-a-computed-field-both-computed-and-databound-to-a-field)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  This may not be the most efficient way to solve this but it works.

var cost1 = getComponent('ItemCost1').getValue();
document1.replaceItemValue("ItemCost_1", cost1),

You can put this in a QuerySave event & it works well.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to let the Computed Field do the work and put the targeted field into a place that is not displayed to the user but is visible on the XPage. Something like this:

```
<xp:table id="dataTable">
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Price Per Day" id="label1"></xp:label>
            </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="PricePerDayEB1" value="#{document1.PricePerDay}" defaultValue="25">
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertNumber type="currency"></xp:convertNumber>
                </xp:this.converter>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dataTable">
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Days" id="label2"></xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="DaysEB1" value="#{document1.Days}" defaultValue="1">
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertNumber type="number" integerOnly="true">
                    </xp:convertNumber>
                </xp:this.converter>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dataTable">
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Computed Total" id="label3"></xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="compTotalCF1">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var PricePerDayEB1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = getComponent("PricePerDayEB1");
var DaysEB1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = getComponent("DaysEB1");
var TotalEB1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = getComponent("TotalEB1");

var ppd = PricePerDayEB1.getValue();
var days = DaysEB1.getValue();
var total = ppd*days

TotalEB1.setValue(total);
return total;
}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr style="display:none;">
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Bound Total" id="label4"></xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="TotalEB1" value="#{document1.Total}">
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
                </xp:this.converter>
            </xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td colspan="2">
            <xp:button value="Submit" id="button1">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

Happy coding

/Newbs